# Why the nextjs 13 server actions does not work properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fetch-api

I am practicing a little project to fetch data from mockapi.io which is a mock api it is not showing the fetched data in the browser. No errors and nothing it is just blank I also get the fetched array data in the console of the server.

```
import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";

export interface Product {
  id?: number;
  product: string;
  price: string;
}

async function ProductsList() {
const res = await fetch("https://64f2c28cedfa0459f6c5fe2c.mockapi.io/products", {
    cache: 'no-cache',
  });
 const products: Product[] = await res.json();
 console.log(products);
  return (
    <>
        {products.map((product) => {
        <p key={product.id}>
          <Link href="/" className="text-gray-900 bg-red-600 ">
            {" "}
            {product.id}
          </Link>
        </p>;
      })}
    </>
  );
}

export default ProductsList;
```

Products page code

```
import ProductsList from "./ProductsList";
import React from "react";
function page() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ProductsList />
    </div>
  );
}

export default page;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ***"map"*** function, you are not returning anything within "{}", which means nothing is being rendered.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";

export interface Product {
  id?: number;
  product: string;
  price: string;
}

async function fetchProducts() {
  const res = await fetch("https://64f2c28cedfa0459f6c5fe2c.mockapi.io/products", {
    cache: 'no-cache',
  });
  const products: Product[] = await res.json();
  return products;
}

function ProductsList() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState<Product[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProducts().then((data) => {
      setProducts(data);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {products.map((product) => (
        <p key={product.id}>
          <Link href="/" className="text-gray-900 bg-red-600 ">
            {product.id}
          </Link>
        </p>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

export default ProductsList;
```

Now ***"ProductsList"*** should render fetched data.

Comment: The reason why it was not showing the data was the return keyword and the rest of the code was fine. Thank you for pointing out.